# ActiveMQ Artemis I can browse message by selector but not receive

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have strange problem we use ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0 and artemis-jms-client-all:2.18.0 as a client dependency. We can browse message by selector `JMSMessageID='some-id'`, but we can't receive it by `MessageConsumer`. Below is code representing this problem (I get IllegalStateException("receive== null")). How to debug this problem? This happens in about 30 of 100.000 messages

```java
Connection connection = null;
Session session = null;
String selector = "JMSMessageID='" + id + "'";
try {
    connection = activeMQJMSConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    Queue deadQueue = session.createQueue("hospital");
    connection.start();

    QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(deadQueue, selector);
    Enumeration e = browser.getEnumeration();
    int foundedElements = 0;
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        Message message = (Message) e.nextElement();
        foundedElements++;
    }
    browser.close();
    if (foundedElements != 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("foundedElements!=1");
    }
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(deadQueue, selector);
    Message receive = messageConsumer.receive(1000);
    if (receive == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("receive== null");
    }
    messageConsumer.close();

    session.commit();
    session.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        session.rollback();
        session.close();
    } catch (JMSException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To receive return the same message that browse did.

Comment: Other concurrent consumers could consume the message browsed. Are you using multiple consumer? Are you able to browse the message again after the receive fails?

Comment: I could repeat this problem over and over, only one consumer

Comment: I'm using artemis-jms-client-all:2.18.0 as a client dependency

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and updated it a bit to try to reproduce the problem on ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0, but it succeeds every time:

```java
final String MESSAGE = "This is a text message";
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()) {
   Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
   Queue deadQueue = session.createQueue("hospital");
   connection.start();

   MessageProducer mp = session.createProducer(deadQueue);
   Message m = session.createTextMessage(MESSAGE);
   mp.send(m);
   session.commit();
   String selector = "JMSMessageID='" + m.getJMSMessageID() + "'";

   QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(deadQueue, selector);
   Enumeration e = browser.getEnumeration();
   int foundedElements = 0;
   while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      e.nextElement();
      foundedElements++;
   }
   browser.close();
   if (foundedElements != 1) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("foundedElements != 1");
   }

   MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(deadQueue, selector);
   Message receive = messageConsumer.receive(1000);
   if (receive == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("receive == null");
   } else if (!((TextMessage)receive).getText().equals(MESSAGE)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("messages don't match");
   }
   messageConsumer.close();

   session.commit();
   session.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

I was using the core JMS client library.

However, when I switched to the **OpenWire** JMS library the code failed. If you are also using the OpenWire JMS client then I believe you're hitting [ARTEMIS-3916](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3916). In this case I recommend you either change the JMS implementation you're using to the core JMS client or upgrade your broker to *at least* 2.25.0 although it would be ideal if you upgraded to the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/).

Comment: My connections string looks like:tcp://ip:61616 and on broker side the are default settings so I'm not sure wich protocol is under the hood. Reproducing o this problem could be hard  I'm also don't know how to do it in fresh env. I have backup from production env with this broken state.

Comment: Deeper investigation is unlikely without a way to reproduce the problem. Have you tried on a later version of the broker/client?